# Facebook login via PHP cURL - cookies

Tags: facebook, curl, authentication

I have got this code :

```
$login_email = '***';
$login_pass = '****';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
$page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
echo $page;
```

Facebook is saying, that i should turn on cookies in the browser. The file cookies.txt is empty.

Comment: And what is `$s` you're using for `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`?

Comment: I have edited it and it still does not work.

Comment: You are not supposed to login to Facebook this way, and they are actively taking measures against it. If you want to interact with Facebook – use their API.

Comment: i would like to use their API, but i cannot send a message to someone with it. I want to send message from my user (my name and surname).

Comment: You should also never ask a person for their Facebook username & password. If you want to send messages to a Facebook friend have you checked out the Send Dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog